# git: 3 commits ahead from original repo

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-fetch

I am new to git, so sorry for this noob question.

The changes which were made in original repo in GitHub by others, I updated those changes in my local copy from the original repo and committed to my forked repo, now it is showing 3 commits ahead, inspite of it being identical to the original repo, what should I do? How can I make it even with the original repo? It showing me to pull request changes which are already done in the original repo

I was using Github desktop
,I did the following

```
1)Change Remote repository in Repository/Repository Settings/Remote/Primary Remote Repository to the the repository I have forked my repo.
2)Press "Fetch Origin" button on the main screen.
3)Press "Pull Origin" button on the main screen.
4)Change Back "Primary Remote Repository" to my fork repository.
5)Press "Fetch Origin" button on the main screen.//This step I skipped
6)Press "Push Origin" button on the main screen.
```

I wanted my forked repo to be identical to original repo, which I achieved, but it is showing 3 commits ahead

Comment: Does it still show "3 ahead" after a `git fetch`? How exactly did you put these changes into your local copy?

Comment: @Thilo check the edit

Comment: What happens if you follow these steps again (not skipping any)?  And is the last commit displayed on Github (web interface) the same for both the upstream repo and your fork (including the commit hash)?  If the repos are public, you can include a link here.

Comment: @Thilo this is my forked repo https://github.com/agh372/susi_android ...those steps are to sync a fork with the original repository

Comment: Fetching and then pulling makes the first fetch redundant. Do you know what each thing does?

Comment: You have the same files as the original, but how you arrived there is different, by this commit: https://github.com/fossasia/susi_android/commit/20211d7fe0f40fc346154db7e6cce3401756d5fd vs https://github.com/fossasia/susi_android/commit/853c2b44f7bd9ca523b6ff00de46b8d99c4483f2  (note that the hash and timestamps differ, even though the contents are the same).

Comment: @Thilo so what should I do now?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah but those steps were actually given by GitHub desktop developers in one of their issues https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1785

Comment: @Thilo if I revert these commits, will it still remain the same as original repo?

Comment: You can delete the `development` branch in your fork, check it out again to match the one from upstream and then make sure you never push to that directly, but always pull it from there. So you'd only make branches for the PR you want to push.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks, but one query, how should I update my development branch before pulling